# react-pdf failing to render base64 PDF data, interpreting as hex string

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I'm trying to use the react-pdf library to display a base64 encoded PDF file. The B64 data is accurate, as it loads in an iframe as such:

```
 <iframe
   className={css.previewIframe}
   src={`data:application/pdf;base64,${
     this.props.encodedPdf
   }`}
 />
```

However, if I insert the data into a react-pdf document as such, I get an error:

```
<Document file={this.props.encodedPdf} />
```

The Document is rendered with an error message `Failed to load PDF file.`, and the console logs the following error: `InvalidPDFException {name: "InvalidPDFException", message: "Invalid PDF structure"}`

I also get a lot of warnings like the following: `Warning: Ignoring invalid character "109" in hex string`

[image: sti]

The [documentation](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) clearly states that the file prop can be B64 encoded content. Any idea on what the issue could be? Here is the B64 data if needed:

```
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
```

If I add `data:application/pdf;base64,` to the beginning of the string, there are no errors, but also nothing is rendered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was:

1. I needed data:application/pdf;base64, in front of the string
2. I did not have a  component inside of my  component. See https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/203

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is exactly what we need.